# How to determine if something is actually statistically significant with multiple attributes

Tags: statistical-significance, predictive-models, feature-selection

So I'm a bit of a newb to statistics, so forgive me (or better, correct me), if I get any terminology wrong.

If I have a population of 1000 people, and 400 of those people have an attribute, A.

Everyone in that population also has a bunch of other attributes, some of which are likely correlated to A.  I'd like to find whatever attributes I can that are predictive.  Is there some kind of accepted algorithm / procedure for doing so.  (I don't have the full population either, so I'm looking to predict whether a given attribute has any kind of relevance to a member of the population having the attribute A).

Comment: That's a definite improvement, thanks. So your working hypothesis would be that B1 is associated with A being unlikely, and the corresponding null hypothesis would be that B1 and A are independent (that the chance of B1 being present is unaffected by whether or not A is there)? ... One potential issue is if you're deciding what to test (or even the direction of your alternative) on the basis of what you saw in the sample you're testing on (if that's not the case it would be good to clarify).  ... You also seem to imply at the end a concern with testing many pairs of variables. Is that right?

Comment: There's another potential issue, which relates to whether you have the entire population of interest (i.e. the ones you wish to make inferences about). If you do, it's not a statistical problem. Hypothesis tests are about inferring whether statements about population characteristics are consistent with information from samples -- if you have the population there's nothing to infer, you can just see if a statement is true.